# VLOOKUP() to a Table on a different worksheet returning an #N/A error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have 2 tables, daily entry

[image: daily entry]

and summary

[image: summary]

My formula in `BQ20` of the summary table is currently:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(BQ5,Table11[DATE],1,FALSE),VLOOKUP('SUMMARY (NEW)'!B20,'DAILY ENTRY'!A:H,8,FALSE),"")
```

`Table11[DATE]` is just column `A` in the daily entry table.

I am trying to pick up the `COST` and `QTY` values from the daily entry table to the summary table. However, when I use the above formula I get an `#N/A` error.

Been trying to make this work for a week now. Am I using the wrong formula?

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP()` works by looking up its first argument in the *first* column of the range specified in the second argument.

Your second argument's first column should be the `ITEM` column, not the first column  of the table.

The corrected formula for `BQ20` is:

```dart
=IF(VLOOKUP(BQ5,Table11[DATE],1,FALSE),VLOOKUP('SUMMARY (NEW)'!B20,Table11[[ITEM]:[COST]],5,FALSE),"")
```

---

However, this formula is still fundamentally flawed. It *won't* pick up the correct item based on the date as there is no, and cannot ever be a, link between the two `VLOOKUP()`. (Attempting to do so is what led to the `#N/A` error.)

One solution for this uses arrays and the `SUMPRODUCT()` function:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(Table11[COST]*(Table11[DATE]=$BQ$5)*(Table11[ITEM]=$B20))
```

**Caveats:**

- This simple formula only works correctly if the values required to be looked up are numbers.
- It only works correctly if the items are unique for each date.

Both these limitations can be overcome with more complex versions of the formula.

EDIT:

As the OP has discovered, there is an equivalent formula to the above that uses `SUMIFS()` instead of `SUMPRODUCT()`:

```dart
=SUMIFS(Table11[COST],Table11[DATE],$BQ$5,Table11[ITEM],$B20)
```

The same caveats apply to this formula as well.

---

There is an alternative solution that *does* use `VLOOKUP()`, but it requires a helper column.

Add a helper column to the daily entry Table:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in all the cells of the `Helper` column:

```dart
=Table11[[#This Row],[DATE]]&Table11[[#This Row],[ITEM]]
```

Enter the following formula in `BQ20`:

```dart
=VLOOKUP($BQ$5&$B20,Table11[[Helper]:[COST]],9,FALSE)
```

Note that this formula works correctly with non-number values and non-unique items, as is.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I tried with the helper column but that seem to come up with an error. A couple of the guys at work and myself was playing around with it and we end up with this formula that worked '=SUMIFS('DAILY ENTRY'!$H:$H,'DAILY ENTRY'!$A:$A,'SUMMARY (NEW)'!LR$5:LS$5,'DAILY ENTRY'!$D:$D,'SUMMARY (NEW)'!$B20)'

Comment: @Nao Yes. That is essentially the same formula as the `SUMPRODUCT()` version I supplied. I've added the `SUMIFS()` variation to the answer (using easier to understand structured references, of course). I'm surprised that you couldn't get the `SUMPRODUCT()` formula to work. (I'm also surprised that you couldn't get the helper column version to work ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ) Just a little note - other than using structured references, your formula can be improved by removing the unnecessary current sheet references and `LS$5`: `=SUMIFS('DAILY ENTRY'!$H:$H,'DAILY ENTRY'!$A:$A,LR$5,'DAILY ENTRY'!$D:$D,$B20)`.